# Getting data from database in a webmethod return null in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, json, database, vb.net

I am trying to get data from a stored procedure in a webmethod inside an asmx service but whatever I try it returns null.

```
<WebMethod()>
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet:=False, 
XmlSerializeString:=False)>
Public Function SendIdDocuments(ByVal idReferto As String)
'This id has been sent from ajax as json and now I am converting it to string 
'in order to use it as parameter in stored procedure.

Dim idRef As String = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(idReferto)
Dim dtRefertoDocIndex As DataTable = operations.G_REPORT_BY_ID(idRef)
Dim version As String = dtRefertoDocIndex.Rows(0)("VERSION")
MsgBox(Cstr(version))
End If
```

I have tried these:

```
1) Dim dtRefertoDocIndex As DataTable = operations.G_REPORT_BY_ID(Cstr(idRef)) 
2) Dim dtRefertoDocIndex As DataTable = operations.G_REPORT_BY_ID(idRef.ToString)
```

These dont work too. I have checked the idRef that has a value and also data from database isn't returning null and version has a value, but in the code dtRefertoDocIndex is null and for this reason version comes as null too. Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Not enough info to debug.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: What is operations.G_REPORT_BY_ID?  is that a method in you code that runs the stored procedure?  If so can we see that.  Why JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(idReferto) when it's already a string?  Why not pass that direct to your G_REPORY_BY_ID method?

Answer (score 0):

A few things. Obviously you can't really use msgbox.

Next up, .net should return JSON without you having to specify it, but we can leave that.

Your web method WILL automatic split out the parameters for you.

So, your web method ALSO needs to be a function that RETURNS a value, say a string

thus it should be:

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Function SendIdDocuments(ByVal idReferto As String) as string

    Dim dtRefertoDocIndex As DataTable = operations.G_REPORT_BY_ID(idRef)
    Dim strResult as string = dtRefertoDocIndex.Rows(0)("VERSION")
    return strResult

End If
```

Note this part:   Public function bla bla bla) ***as string*** <---- your function HAS to return something, right?

Now WHY did I create a string to hold the return value and THEN return it?

Answer:

Because  I do NOT want to take a chance that the return type is a column cell, or ANY OTHER data type OTHER then a string. So, to be 100%, 200%, 300% of the correct data type being returned? I create a nice separate string, and stuff the value into that string, and THEN return that SIMPLE string type. This removes ANY doubt that we ARE in fact returning a simple string type. When we execute the return strResult?

It will be converted back into a json result.

Ok, now, lets setup the JavaScript (client side) ajax call.

jQuery:

```
        function GetDocByID() {

            var MyDocID = 123;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'WebService1.asmx/MakeName',
                data: JSON.stringify({idReferto: MyDocID}),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                datatype: "json",
                success: function (em) {
                    alert('VERSION result = ' + em.d);
                }
            });
        }
```

If you not using jQuery, then of course you have to re-write above.

So, .net will automatic convert to and from json for you. And ALSO VERY careful note how the parameter name in JavaScript (jQuery) MUST match the parameters in the public function you created.

Here is another simple example. We pass firstname, last name, and return the two as a single string:

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Function MakeName(FirstName As String, LastName As String) As String

    Dim strResult As String = ""

    strResult = FirstName & " " & LastName

    Return strResult

End Function
```

and the js/jQuery is:

```
        function GetNameTest() {

            var MyFirstName = 'Albert';
            var MyLastName = 'Kallal';

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'WebService1.asmx/MakeName',
                data: JSON.stringify({ FirstName: MyFirstName, LastName: MyLastName }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                datatype: "json",
                success: function (em) {
                    alert('name result = ' + em.d);
                }
            });
        }
```

Note again HOW we used the actual vb.net FirstName and LastName DEFINED in the public function.

Note again: the function has a return value (string).

And if you look at the web service template, note that you WANT to un-comment the FIRST line as outlined like this:

```
' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()>
```

Comment: I have made the part when I call webmethod in ajax jquery and I also have returned a value in function (webmethod), but I didnt want to write so much code in order to show just the more important part of the issue. The problem is that the function stuck in "Dim version As String" even if I remove msgbox it happens the same thing, the ajax call returns 500 error.

Comment: You have to show/post more code then. Post the method, and the post your js. The above steps outlined should work. If you have friendly URL's turned on - then in routeconfig.vb, commend out this line settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent. The above short js ajax call, and the above short vb code stub is all that you need for this to work. Try above FirstName + LastName example and see if that works. You also don't mention if you using jQuery, since my above examples assume this. You can quite easy make ajax calls without jQuery, but you not noted which you are using.